# Handling site-wide URL rewrites with PHP

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, redirect, canonical-link

I'm looking into the feasibility of using PHP - instead of `mod_rewrite` - to handle URL canonicalization.  I'm looking to be able to map a large number of different URLs to a given physical PHP page, and handle 301's and 404's in a more centralized and maintainable way.  This will include common misspellings, aliases, search engine friendly URL parameters, and the like.  These needs seem well outside the power of `mod_rewrite`, so I'm looking into other options.

I'm thinking I would create a `canonical.php` script which I map every page to with the following in .htaccess ([borrowed from this post](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?t=51923)):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ canonical.php/$1?%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

And then `canonical.php` would do whatever URL parsing / db lookups / redirects / etc. are necessary, then simply include `/the/appropriate/file.php` for the given request.

Is this a reasonable course of action?  Is such functionality actually feasible with `mod_rewrite` directly?  (DB lookups and the like aside) will this be distinctly slower than `mod_rewrite`?  Is there any other methodology that's more robust than a PHP wrapper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're talking about routing, which plenty of frameworks do. Take a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115629/simplest-php-routing-framework

Answer (score 0):

What I would suggest and what I use is a php file that gets called everytime when a 404 is encountered and it stores the url encountered.
Then once a week I go to the management console and I map the wrongly spelled mistyped, old urls, searchengine's history url's to the current existing urls then I hit the parse button and it spews out a new updated .htaccess file out for me.

That way you lighten the load on your database, loading time, compiling time and redirecting time.

Just my 2 cents.

Comment: Good idea, I'm looking for more than that, but auto-generating an .htaccess file is not a bad plan.  I wonder if there's a point where the number of lines in .htaccess could introduce a greater slowdown than a more dynamic solution.

Comment: There are people who have 30k+ line's of anti bot, hack, spam processed via .htaccess and they have no problems concerning speed.

Answer (score 0):

Haven't had a chance to test this, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13612810/113632) pointed me at Apache's [`FallbackResource`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_dir.html#fallbackresource) directive, which sounds very promising.