# Routing URL Path with PHP and Apache

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-routing, front-controller

I am trying to create a nice url structure for my site.

My router class will only work if the url is in the style of ?something=value.

How do I get it so it will work like:

```
/something/value
```

In my .htaccess I have:

```
Options FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule !\.(js|txt|gif|jpg|png)$ index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

And in my router class I'm making:

```
class init {

    function __construct()
    {

    $URL = substr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 19) ;
    $URLElements = explode('/', $URL) ; // Adjust if needed.

    $class = $URLElements[0] ;
    $method = $URLElements[1] ;

    if(($t = substr_count($URL, '/')) > 1)
    {
        for($i=2;$i<$t+1;$i++) {
            echo $URLElements[$i].'<br />';
        }
    }
    }
```

### }

Thanks to Jason, my .htaccess is now just:

```
FallbackResource /t2013/public_html/index.php
```

Comment: Do you only want to redirect that structure?

Comment: Dude wrong approach! You need something like this  ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ yourscrpit.php?var1=$1&var2=$2 in your .htaccess

Comment: @pregmatch But it has to work with classes and methods with unlimited parameters, i.e. classname/method/param1/param2/param3 etc.

Comment: @pregmatch, dude, brittle approach :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For a quick way to handle [Front-end Controllers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_Controller_pattern) with Apache, use [`FallbackResource`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_dir.html#fallbackresource) and parse the URL with PHP.

```
FallbackResource /index.php
```

Comment: How would I implement this in my case? Haven't heard of this before.

Comment: Reading the links I provided should be a good start. After that, check out PHP functions like [`parse_url`](http://php.net/parse_url).

Comment: Interesting... hadn't run across that before in the many various front controller configurations I have worked with or seen posted about in places like StackOverflow.  Very straightforward implementation.

Comment: It was added as of Apache 2.2.17 (or cerca). I found it to be more performant in such cases. Agreed it is unused. May do a blog post soon.

Comment: @Jason McCreary That's pretty awesum, makes the whole process much simpler, I have edited my post to reflect what I now have in case you wish to comment further :).

Answer (score 1):

htaccess should be something like this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)/([^/\.]+)$ $1.php?$2=$3 [QSA]
```

so for example

/home/something/value would be redirected to /home.php?something=value

Give it a go, not completely sure on this but have done something similar before.

Answer (score 0):

From a PHP perspective, you would just need to adjust your init class to key off of `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` instead of `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`.  You are not showing your full logic here, but my guess is that you would simply trim the first `/` and then explode the URI on `/` to get at the component parts.

From an .htaccess standpoint, you could just change your last line to be:

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [L,QSA]
```

You don't need to specifically detect images/css/js here as that `RewriteCond` already makes exceptions to the rewrite rule for any actual files or directories.  Note that in the `RewriteRule` I did leave the Query String Append (QSA) flag in place in case you still wanted to do something like `/controller?some=string&of=data`  If you don't anticipate using query strings at all with your new URI's, then you can omit this flag.

Comment: It's wasteful to enable `mod_rewrite` and never *rewrite* the URL.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary I agree it is a performance drain (especially when using mod_rewrite in .htaccess).  I honestly like your answer on this question better than mine, but was unaware of it.  I will leave answer here in case poster opts not to use your solution or doesn't have ability to enable `mod_dir` for whatever reason.