# How do i get the equivalent of PHP -S localhost:8888 -t public in my configs

Tags: php, apache, xampp

IDE: vscode
OS: windows 11
PHP: Xampp

**Question 1**
What is the `-t public` equivalent in the `https-vhosts.conf` (or correct file)?
current `https-vhosts.conf` setup.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/vscode/main_site/public"
    ServerName mainsite
</VirtualHost>
```

**File Structure**

```
SERVER_DOC_ROOT/Core
SERVER_DOC_ROOT/Controllers
SERVER_DOC_ROOT/Public
SERVER_DOC_ROOT/views
SERVER_DOC_ROOT/config.php
SERVER_DOC_ROOT/routes.php
SERVER_DOC_ROOT/bootstrap.php
```

**Why**
The tutorial I am following to learn php has me starting the server like this in the CLI `PHP -S localhost:8888 -t public` where public is a subfolder of my root directory. *I would like to just start xampp*

**issue**
It loads a partial page (my custom 404 page not found) doesn't route the urls or show the index.view.php file i have outside of public in SERVER_DOC_ROOT/views.
The instructor said this was to help protect the content not in the public folder. (security) Idk if it does or not, argue away.

Thanks in advance.
**index.php in the public folder**

```
<?php 
use Core\Session;

const BASE_PATH = __DIR__ . '/../';
const START_TRAIL = 'Home'; // for breadcrumbs
const START_TRAIL_LINK = '/index'; // for breadcrumbs
require BASE_PATH . 'Core/functions.php';


spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    $class = str_replace('\\', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $class);
    require basePath("{$class}.php");
});

require basePath('bootstrap.php');

$router = new \Core\Router();

$routes = require basePath('routes.php');
$uri = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])['path'];

$method = $_POST['_method'] ?? $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'];

$router->route($uri, $method);
```

**Router.php inside Core folder**

```
<?php
namespace Core;

use Core\Middleware\Auth;
use Core\Middleware\Guest;
use Core\Middleware\Middleware;

class Router{
    protected $routes = [];

    public function add($method, $uri, $controller){
        $this->routes[]= [
            'uri' => $uri,
            'controller' => $controller,
            'method' => $method ,
            'middleware' => null
        ];
        return $this;
    }
    public function get($uri, $controller){
        return $this->add('GET',$uri, $controller);
    }
    public function post($uri, $controller){
        return $this->add('POST',$uri, $controller);
    }
    public function delete($uri, $controller){
        return $this->add('DELETE',$uri, $controller);
    }
    public function patch($uri, $controller){
        return $this->add('PATCH',$uri, $controller);
    }
    public function put($uri, $controller){
        return $this->add('PUT',$uri, $controller);
    }
    public function only($key){ //this will pull the most recent entry in the array
        
        $this->routes[array_key_last($this->routes)]['middleware'] =$key;
        return $this;
    }

    public function route($uri, $method){
        foreach($this->routes as $route){
            if($route['uri'] === $uri && $route['method'] === strtoupper($method) ){

                //check if middleware exist
               // Middleware::resolve($route['middleware']);

                return require basePath('Http/Controllers/'.$route['controller']);
            
            }
        }
        $this->abort();

    }
    protected function abort($code = 404) {
        http_response_code($code);
        require basePath("views/{$code}.php");
        die();
    }
}
```

**routes.php in SERVER_DOC_ROOT**

```
<?php   

$router->get('/index',      'index.php');
$router->get('/contact',      'contact.php');
$router->get('/about',      'about.php');
(I have more just shortened as I cant even get the /index to load)
```

**bootstrap.php in SERVER_DOC_ROOT**

```
<?php
use Core\App;
use Core\Container;
use Core\Database;

$container = new Container();
//                KEY              build up
$container->bind('Core\Database', function() {
    $config = require basePath('config.php');
    return new Database($config['database']);
});

App::setContainer($container);
```

**functions.php in Core folder**

```
<?php

use Core\Response;
use Core\App;

function dd($value)
{
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump($value);
    echo "</pre>";

    die();
};
function urlIs($value)
{
    //we are evauluating if the page matches the current page.
    // since this is a boolean it will return true or false
    return $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] === $value;
};
function authorize($condition, $status = Response::FORBIDDEN)
{
    if (!$condition) {
        abort($status);
    }
}
function basePath($value)
{
    return BASE_PATH . $value;
}
function view($value, $attr = [])
{
    extract($attr);
    require basePath('views/' . $value);
}
function partials($value, $attr = [])
{
    extract($attr);
    require basePath('views/partials/' . $value);
}
function abort($code = 404)
{
    http_response_code($code);
    require basePath("views/{$code}.php");
    die();
}
function redirect($path)
{
    header("location: {$path}");
    exit();
}
```

** .htaccess **

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /main_site/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /main_site/public/index.php [L]
```

**UPDATE 1** 
I found this other [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13612738/routing-url-path-with-php-and-apache) on stack from 2012. It is getting me closer. I navigate to my page as `http://localhost` and it loads to a 404 but after i click a link anywhere on my page it loads

**httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/vscode/main_site/public"
    ServerName mainsite
    FallbackResource /index.php
</VirtualHost>
```

**update 2** added this line to my routes folder and am now not getting the initial 404 page.

```
$router->get('/',      'index.php');
```

Comment: Everything above the document root will not be directly accessible via HTTP from the outside, so that's correct regarding the security aspect. What your specific problem is now, is a bit unclear though. When you request `http:/mainsite/` in your browser now, it should show the specified DirectoryIndex file from the `public` folder, if there is one - and if not, either a directory listing, or a 403. Not sure what exactly you expect to _"show the index.view.php file i have outside of public in SERVER_DOC_ROOT/views"_ now?

Comment: @CBroe so in vs code when i start a host for the site using cli `PHP -S localhost:8888 -t public` it router controller routes to php files in controller and views that are not in the public folder. I dont understand how to  make that happen in apache with the configs.

Comment: You did not actually specify a router _script_ with the command you have shown, so I am not exactly sure _which_ part of the functionality of the build-in webserver you are actually referring to here now. Maybe you should go find a tutorial, that is more geared towards setting something like that up using Apache in the first place, such as https://www.educative.io/answers/how-to-create-a-basic-php-router

Comment: @CBroe using the link you gave me. I created an htacess file. I am loading the required files for all pages but not loading the dynamic center content. I am getting a 404 not found.